# an arbitrary Polynomial : C code

Tags: c

I was asked to write a C code that evaluates an arbitrary polynomial, I made this one but there seem to be a bug somewhere.

This my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main (void) {
//initialize the variables
float x=0;
float a1=0;
float a2=0;
float a3=0;
float a0=0;
float fx=0;

printf("enter a0, a1, a2, a3. and your x value in the meintioned order,\nmake a single space between your inputs\n");
scanf("%f, %f, %f, %f, %f", &a0, &a1, &a2, &a3, &x); //reading the values of a1, a2, a3, a0, and x

fx= ((a3 * pow (x, 3)) + (a2 * pow (x, 2)) + (a1 * pow (x, 1)) + (a0 * pow (x, 0)));

printf("f(x) = %lf", fx);

return 0;
}
```

this is my input, after a number of tries I found out that the code is outputting the value of the first thing user inputs.

I edited my code to show me what is really happening :

```
enter a0, a1, a2, a3. and your x value in the mentioned order,
make a single space between your inputs
44 4 4 4 4
0.000000 + 0.000000 + 0.000000 + 44.000000 = f(x) = 44.000000
```

and that was the output!

Comment: Always check the return value from `scanf`. You ask for 5 numbers, so the return value should be 5. If you had checked, you would find that `scanf` returned 1, meaning that only the first number was read.

Comment: Your code does not create the output you show. Where is the first part of the last line printed? _0.000000 + 0.000000 + 0.000000 + 44.000000 =_ Are there more inconsistencies hidden?

Answer (score 0):

There is inconsistency with the Format and input, either change the format or the way you input,

For format: try without the `,` comma within the format `" "` qoutes

```
scanf("%f %f %f %f %f", &a0, &a1, &a2, &a3, &x); //reading the values of a1, a2, a3, a0, and x
```

For input: change the input to `44,4,4,4,4` and it'll work with the current way you have

```
scanf("%f,%f,%f,%f,%f", &a0, &a1, &a2, &a3, &x); //reading the values of a1, a2, a3, a0, and x
```